# JavaScript For Loop - execution termination condition

Tags: javascript

I was looking at source code of `Ext` object in ExtJs docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/source/Ext.html#Ext) and I noticed this `for` loop:

```
for (j = enumerables.length; j--;) {
    k = enumerables[j];
    if (config.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        object[k] = config[k];
    }
}
```

So, normally in a `for` loop, we have do initialization, specify condition and then increment/decrement the counter. I do see an initial condition and `j--` which decrements the counter after each iteration. However, what I can't figure out is how is the loop going to be terminated? I neither see any condition nor a `break` keyword that will terminate the loop.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `j--` *is* the loop condition, that's how it will terminate.  the trailing `;)` is the missing increment/decrement.

The j-- construct both decrements j and tests the old un-decremented value for non-zero to decide whether to continue looping.  The loop stops when j is zero; below the loop, the value of j will be -1.

The key parts of the for loop to look for are the semicolons -- `for ( ; ; )`
Any valid expression (or comma-separated expression list) can go in any of the three slots, before, between, and after the semicolons.

The loop initializers go after the `(` and before the first `;`.  The loop condition is the value of the expression between the two `; ;`.  The post-loop update goes after the last `;` and before the `)`.

Comment: That is correct. This approach is often used to improve the performance of a loop, to decrement the iterator toward 0 instead of incrementing it.

Comment: eg the classic C string copy loop:  `for ( ; *d++ = *s++ ; ) ;` (with apologies to the original, which used `while`)

Comment: Why would the loop stop when j is 0?

Comment: Because 0 is implicitly converted to the boolean value `false`.

Comment: because the conditional tests (if, while, for, do) test for truthy, and 0, false, null, undefined, "" (empty string) (and in php, "0" string containing a single zero - go figure) are all "falsy"